# azure postgres pg_restore fails to find dump file in container

Tags: postgresql, azure, powershell, pg-dump, pg-restore

I have created an Azure Postgres database.  Now I'm trying to populate it from a dump file.  I uploaded the file to an Azure container. It gives me a url for the file. Then I try to *pg_restore* from a Cloud Shell (powershell) like this:

```
pg_restore -v --no-owner --host=user@<database-name>.postgres.database.azure.com --port=5432 --username=user@<database-name> --dbname=<database-name> <url-to-container-file>
```

But it give error:

> pg_restore: error: could not open input file
> "<url-to-container-file":
> No such file or directory

Any hints on why Azure Cloud Shell can't find an Azure Container file?

Comment: A URL is not a file.  Does Microsoft do some magic here to make the URL look like a file?  Can you do `dir` on it?  Can you do `more` on it?

Comment: In Azure, a lot of things happen behind the scenes on virtual machines that you don't have access to.  Instead, they give you urls to things you need.